# made a shell to run script on startup, suddently it gives me an importerror

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I followed this guide: [guide](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Launch-Python-script-on-startup/) to create a startupfile which excecutes a python file on startup.

in step 2 it says I have to test the startupfile I just created and suddently my script says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Display.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyowm
ImportError: No module named pyowm
```

the python file works perfect if I run it directly.

what I allready tried: run pip again to see if the lib was okay
check the /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages folder to see if it was there and it is.

I think this is a python issue and not a RaspberryPi issue thats why I uploaded it here.

runned by:

> sh launcher.sh

inside is:

```
#!/bin/sh
# launcher.sh
# navigate to home directory, then to this directory, then execute python script, then back home

cd /
cd /home/pi/arduino/Python/Main/Master
sudo python Display.py
cd /
```

Comment: what command are you giving to run it?

Comment: `sh launcher.sh`

Comment: what is inside `launcher.sh`?

Comment: look at the main post edited it

Comment: So what kind of python-versions you got? Is the python-interpreter you use defined in your bash-env or you only got one single executable system-wide? Maybe your start-script is calling python2, while you want to call python3 (so install-state is different)?

Comment: Im using python 3.4 so that could be it! How do i define that Im using 3.4 and not 2.7. Would `sudo python3 Display.py` suffice?

Comment: And it worked brilliantly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix: define the version of python which will be used. It used python 2.7. Yet the lib was for 3.4.